# Function specialization to access struct members with getter using enum

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have an enum and a struct

```
enum STORE_ENUM { A_DATA, B_DATA, C_DATA, D_DATA };
struct Store {
   int a;
   char b;
   long c;
   bool d;

}
```

and I want to access its members with a specialized get function that basically looks like this

```
T get(STORE_ENUM,store s);
```

and it returns the appropriate type and hopefully statically type checks.
is this possible in C++?

Comment: in c++17 you can use `if constexpr` - but signature must be `template <StoreEnum kind> auto& get(Store&);` But you tagged question with C++11

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  The boost PFR library allows something very similar to how you've envisaged it, e.g.:

```
auto& x = boost::pfr::get<B_DATA>(s);
```

See the tutorial [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_pfr/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

With C++17, you can do the following

```
#include <iostream>

enum struct STORE_ENUM { A_DATA, B_DATA, C_DATA, D_DATA };
struct Store {
   int a;
   char b;
   long c;
   bool d;

};

template<STORE_ENUM storeEnum>
auto get(Store const & s){
    if constexpr (storeEnum == STORE_ENUM::A_DATA) return s.a;
    if constexpr (storeEnum == STORE_ENUM::B_DATA) return s.b;
    if constexpr (storeEnum == STORE_ENUM::C_DATA) return s.c;
    if constexpr (storeEnum == STORE_ENUM::D_DATA) return s.d;
}
int main(){
    auto store = Store{ 0, 'a', 4l, true};
    std::cout << get<STORE_ENUM::A_DATA>( store) << "\n";
    std::cout << get<STORE_ENUM::B_DATA>( store) << "\n";
    std::cout << get<STORE_ENUM::C_DATA>( store) << "\n";
    std::cout << get<STORE_ENUM::D_DATA>( store) << "\n";
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/1vffh3

Comment: the problem with this one is that it doesn't type check incorrect usage.

float f = get<STORE_ENUM::A_DATA>(store);

Comment: @FamousJameis The problem exists even if the type was explicit. to overcome this use something like `float f {get<STORE_ENUM::A_DATA>(store)};`

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, we don't need enums. It uses templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Store
{
    int a;
    char b;
    long c;
    bool d;

    Store() //Default constructor
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = false;
    }

    Store(int a, char b, long c, bool d) //Constructor. Custom values.
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
        this->d = d;
    }

    template <typename T = int,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<T, char>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<T, long>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<T, bool>::value,
                                                 void>::type>
    T GetData()
    {
        if (std::is_same<T, char>::value)
        {
            return b;
        }
        if (std::is_same<T, long>::value)
        {
            return c;
        }
        if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
        {
            return d;
        }
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Store store { 63, '@', 65, true };
    std::cout << store.GetData() << std::endl;
    std::cout << store.GetData<>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << store.GetData<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << store.GetData<char>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << store.GetData<long>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << store.GetData<bool>() << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
63
63
63
@
65
true
```

**Compile**
`clang++ ./main.cpp -std=c++11` or `g++ ./main.cpp -std=c++11`

Check/run this code in https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/FunctionSpecialization#main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

`std::tuple` basically does this, and your type is basically a tuple.  So the *easy* and *fast* way is to just reuse `std::tuple`'s machinery.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) it might look like this:

```
template<STORE_ENUM e>
auto get( Store s ){
  return std::get<(unsigned)e>(std::make_tuple(s.a,s.b,s.c,s.d));
}
template<STORE_ENUM e, class T>
void set( Store& s, T t ){
  std::get<(unsigned)e>(std::tie(s.a,s.b,s.c,s.d))=t;
}
```

This is [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), but the missing bit for [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) is easy:

```
template<STORE_ENUM e>
using store_type = typename std::tuple_element<(unsigned)e, std::tuple<int,char,long,bool>>::type;

template<STORE_ENUM e>
store_type<e> get( Store s ) {
  return std::get<(unsigned)e>(std::make_tuple(s.a,s.b,s.c,s.d));
}

template<STORE_ENUM e>
void set( Store& s, store_type<e> v ){
  std::get<(unsigned)e>(std::tie(s.a,s.b,s.c,s.d))=v;
}
```